# Mailing isn't working in Django AWS Lambda (Zappa) behind a VPC

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, vpc, zappa

I have an AWS lambda function (Django zappa) that is running inside a VPC thus I'm not able to send emails because Lambda isn't connected to the internet, I tried NAT Gatway but with no hope.

- I created a NAT Gatway using one public subnet of the VPC.
- Created another private subnet with a route table that routes 0.0.0.0/0 to the NAT Gateway.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you have any error details of lambda while sending email?

Comment: https://medium.com/@philippholly/aws-lambda-enable-outgoing-internet-access-within-vpc-8dd250e11e12

Answer (score 0):

Go to **VPC Dashboard** and use the **Launch VPC Dashboard**

[image: Launch VPC dashboard]

Create (Allocate) an **elastic IP** address and keep it handy. Select the option **VPC with Public and Private Subnets**
[image: VPC with Public and Private Subnets]

Configure the subnet CIDRs and associate the **elastic IP** created in the previous step in the form. This will create a NAT Gateway and set it up automatically with correct route tables.

Things to note:

- NAT Gateway should always be in the public subnet.
- Route table of Private Subnet should have a route `0.0.0.0/0` to NAT Gateway
- Route table of Public Subnet should have a route `0.0.0.0/0` to Internet Gateway
- Lambda function should be configured with the Private Subnet and not the Public Subnet
- Security Group configured in the lambda function should allow outbound to `0.0.0.0/0` (which is there by default, but you should verify)